# Python subprocess script works on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows

I write a simple script to check the subprocess module and I tested it on both Windows and Linux.

The script works fine on Windows but not on Linux.

The Python interpreter used is version 3 on both.

```
import subprocess
host = input("Enter a host to ping: ")
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "2", host], shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p1.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

Output on Windows:

```
Enter a host to ping: google.com

Pinging google.com [142.250.183.238] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 142.250.183.238: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=120
Reply from 142.250.183.238: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=120

Ping statistics for 142.250.183.238:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 17ms, Average = 16ms
```

On Linux:

```
Enter a host to ping: google.com
ping: usage error: Destination address required
```

What is the difference when running on Linux?.

Comment: Drop the "2" and it will work. What does the "2" request on windows?

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: You will have to be more specific. On Linux -n = Numeric output only,  -c count = Stop  after  sending  count packets

Comment: On a side note: Unless you're using a very old version of 3 then you might want to consider using [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) and its related high-level functions instead of working with `Popen` directly.

Comment: Thank you, yes, the flag was the whole problem. On Linux -c and windows -n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ping command on windows is like `ping -n 2 google.com` but in linux is `ping -c 2 google.com`. Try using `if os.name() == 'posix'` for linux & `if os.name() == 'nt'` for windows and write two commands, one for each OS.